# Can single defer func() be shared by other functions?

Tags: go, error-handling

I see a lot of examples using defer func() inside of a function. Is there a way to keep from repeating it in various places and call it like a normal function?

In this example (and many others) the defer function is nested inside of another function:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    defer func() {
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Exception: %v\n", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }()

    file, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Could not open file")
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v", file)
}
```

Is there a way to move the defer func() outside of main() so it can be used by other functions as well?

Comment: "so it can be used by other functions as well" --- what does it mean? A function under `defer` is called when the _current_ function returns. You can `defer` _any_ function call.

Comment: Yes I kept seeing a more "anonymous" use of defer and didn't realize that it was actually possible to defer any function call.

Comment: By the way, IMO this is a bad example of [`recover`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#recover). Panic and recover is not for normal errors or error reporting so it's not a good idea to "handle" a panic in this way (nor to call it an "Exception").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can defer any function. Where that function is defined isn't important.

This is perfectly valid:

```
func foo() {
    // Do foo
}


func bar() {
    defer foo()
    // Do something before foo
}

func baz() {
    defer foo()
    // Do something else before foo
}
```

But in this case `foo()` will be called once for each invocation of `bar()` and `baz()`. It's not "shared", except in the sense that you don't have to re-write an anonymous function multiple times.

Probably the most common example of this is calling `Close()` in a defer statement:

```
func foo() error {
    f, err := os.Open(...)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close() // "Close()" is obviously not defined here
    // do something with f
}
```

**TL;DR;**

You cannot share a `defer` statement across functions. But as with any other function, the function invoked by `defer`, can be called from multiple places.